# “IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled”

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
string Query = "SELECT [AA], [TEXT] FROM [TABLE] WHERE FK_ML_PROGRAM=200 AND FK_ML_LANGUAGE=" +  Convert.ToInt32(cboLanguage.SelectedIndex) + " AND AA like 'Msg_%' ORDER BY ID ";
LanguageData = DAL.ExecuteDataTable(Query);

private DataRow GetRows(string b)
{
    DataRow[] result_start = LanguageData.Select("AA='" + b.ToString() + "'");
    DataRow Row = result_start[0];

    return Row;
}
```

When I run the application, it throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: most likely your result set is empty, try checking the length of result_start before you try to assign something from it.

Answer (score 5):

`result_start` probably has no elements. You need a check:

```
private DataRow GetRows(string b)
{
    DataRow[] result_start = LanguageData.Select("AA='" + b.ToString() + "'");
    if (results_start.Length > 0)
        return result_start[0];

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You mean I have to add some data to my database which contains table of query ?

Comment: No, you need a condition to check if anything was returned from `LanguageData.Select(...)`. You are probably just getting an empty array returned. Therefore `result_start[0]` will thrown an exception because there is no elements.

Answer (score 1):

It looks likely that the filter is not matching any rows in the data set that had been returned.

You need to check if result_start has rows before attempting to get a particular row from it.